# run commands in active console via command line ConEmu.exe

Tags: conemu, total-commander

Is there are way to have `ConEmu.exe` run a command, e.g. `cd some/path`on *the active console*?

To provide more context, I am attempt to integrate Total Commander (an external file explorer application) with ConEmu.  On Total Commander, I define a start menu item (similar to Macros in Conemu) to execute `ConEmu.exe` like so:

```
 ConEmu.exe -Reuse -Dir %P
```

where `%P` is a parameter in Total Commander value of which is path of the current pane. This works as documented, reuses single ConEmu session or opens one up if none running, and creates a new tab with the default task whose CD is %P (my default task happens to be Git Bash).

To get the same effect on an existing tab, whichever one happens to be active, I attempted:

```
ConEmu.exe -Reuse -run ConEmuC -GuiMacro print cd %P
```

but that doesn't quite work.

Is there a way to get this effect?

Answer (score 0):

When you try to run yours `ConEmu.exe -Reuse -run ConEmuC -GuiMacro print cd %P`, the `ConEmuC` is started in the **new tab** of the **existing** ConEmu window. So, you macro is trying to be executed in that new tab.

Instead, you shall try to run simple

```
ConEmuC -GuiMacro print cd %P
```